# Identifying $C(X\times X)$ with $C(X)\otimes C(X)$

Tags: analysis, operator-algebras

If $X$ is a compact topological space there is the isomorphism $ C(X\times X) \cong C(X) \otimes C(X)$, proved with, for example, Stone-Weierstrass. Is there some way of finding the isomorphic image on the right side of a function on the left? All proofs I know start with a map from right to left by mapping two functions to their product but is there some way to geht a concrete formula for the inverse?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What notion of tensor product are you using here?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The maximal one. Or, if you will, the algebraic one and then taking the closure.

Comment: The closure in $C(X \times X)$? So this isn't one of the abstract tensor products of Banach spaces?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well, in my case it doesn't really matter, so for safety I'll say the maximal tensor product of $C^*$-algebras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the formula for the inverse for the isomorphism of polynomial rings $\mathbb C[x,y]\simeq\mathbb C[x]\otimes\mathbb C[y]$, namely $$\sum a_{mn}x^my^n\mapsto\sum (a_{mn}x^m)\otimes y^n.$$ But the isomorphism $C(X\times X) \cong C(X) \otimes C(X)$ involves the completion of the subspace of finite sums $\sum_{m,n} f_m(x)g_n(y)$. Hence you can have the explicit inverse only on the dense subspace of $C(X\times X)$.

Comment: So, there is no hope i guess? Concretely my $X$ is a compact subset of the $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I'd like to look at the image of the metric.

Comment: There is no hope, even in your case.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway!